# Книги по автоматизации Delphi с MS Word'ом 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, автоматизация, ms-word, ole

В общем я не получил ответа по автоматизации с вордом, хочу почитать материал по этой теме. у меня есть книга "Разработка приложений Ms Office 2007 в DELPHI" автор Юрий Магда. НО там оочень мало написано по нужному мне вопросу с Word'ом. Больше книг на эту тему я не встречал. Жду полезной всячины, кто что знает

Answer (score 1):

Корняков Василий, ["Программирование документов и приложений MS Office в Delphi".](http://www.bhv.ru/books/book.php?id=8135)

Книга раза в 2 толще, указанной вами. Посмотрите, возможно окажется полезной.